# How to Obtain records according to hourly in a list with linq?

Tags: c#, list, linq

I want to get records of list according to hourly such as this :

```
pumpsStatus = pumpsStatus
  .Where(x => x.Date >= dateTimeStart && x.Date <= dateTimeEnd)
  .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Hour)
  .Select(x => x.First())
  .ToList();
```

In this case get me records of list according to hourly in **first day** !!!!

How can i do that?

Comment: How are `dateTimeStart` and `dateTimeEnd` defined? Why do you need to use a `First()` method? Can you share an example data and expected result?

Comment: What do you mean by 'first day'? Of you had `OrderBy` or `OrderByDescending` you wll get the earliest or latest in the list.

Comment: Type of `dateTimeStart , dateTimeEnd` are `DateTime`.

Comment: Could you provide some *example(s)*? The initial `pumpsStatus` and the desired result?

Answer (score 0):

It is a bit hard to answer the question as is since it misses some details. But if I understand it correctly, you want to group your status reports by their (collecting?) hours. If so, you can do it like follows:

```
var hourlyReport = pumpStatuses
    .Where(x => x.Date > startDate && x.Date < endDate)
    .GroupBy(x => x.Date.Hour)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try adding brackets here => Where(x => *(*x.Date >= dateTimeStart && x.Date <= dateTimeEnd*)*)

Comment: I dont use SelectMany . Please check again